# How to fix negative address size when listening to wildcard address?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms, activemq-artemis

**Error in Artemis Console**

AMQ222214: Destination /queue/app/xxx has an inconsistent and negative address size

---

**Scenario**

- The message is available in /queue/app/xxx
- The JMSListener is listening to /queue/app/*

```
     @JmsListener(destination = "/queue/app/*")
```

All of a sudden, the error started appearing and the queue seems to be blocked and the listener does not get any new non-persistent/non-durable messages. The same setup worked for some time.

---

**Observation**

- It seems like, the culprit is that I have kept the *auto-create-expiry-resources* feature turned on. So, on expiry of a message the expiry-queue is created for both the wildcard-queue(/queue/app/*) and the actual-queue(/queue/app/xxx). Post this event, the error starts appearing.
- This issue only impacts the non-persistent/non-durable messages

Any comments on how to fix this?

Comment: I'm seeing the same warning message on a durable queue when there are two receivers on the same queue

Comment: @Alessandro, I suppose this got fixed in 2.16 https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/release-notes-2.16.0

Comment: @Alessandro I could be wrong. Please verify. I am referring to this issue that got closed - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2859

Comment: I've just updated to 2.16. I will give it a week to see if the negative address size messages appear and report back, but for now, I have not seen them anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already a couple of Jiras open related to this:

- [ARTEMIS-2768](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2768)
- [ARTEMIS-2859](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2859)

You can either wait for them to be fixed or contribute a fix yourself. Code contributions are always welcome.